# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `UserViewSerializer`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to attribute Likes to the articles but i don't know why i am getting this error.

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser,PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    username =models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True,default='SOME STRING')
   

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

class LikeUserModel(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='userlikes')
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class UserViewSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    userlikes = UserSerializer(many=True)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields  = ('id','email','username','userlikes',)
```

I defined everything right,no typo or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

email is not a field in your `UserViewSerializer`. Only `userlikes` is. You can either write fields like this:

```
fields  = ('userlikes',)
```

or define your fields within the `UserSerializer` if you don't want all the User model fields.